# closed form of the sequence $a_{n+1} = a_ne^{-a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

There isn't much documentation available for finding closed forms of sequences, given their recurrence relation.

I couldn't find out the closed form of the sequence $$a_{n+1} = a_ne^{-a_n}$$
Given $$a_0 = 1$$
I tried everything from trying to guess then prove by induction to exponential generating functions and I always end up just proving that $0 = 0$.

Do sequences like the aforementioned one have a closed form?
How should I approach this one specifically?

Comment: Idea: does it help to instead look at $b_n=\ln(a_n)$?

Comment: $a_1=1$, then $a_2 = e^{-1}$, $a_3 = e^{-(e^{-1}+1)}$, $a_4 = e^{-(e^{-(e^{-1}+1)}+e^{-1}+1)}$, it's going to be an increasing power tower, I'm not sure what kind of closed form do you expect

Comment: It did get me further than without doing it, but I still end up proving that 0 = 0.

Comment: Given the bizarre looking of the terms, I guess a nice closed form does not exist...

Comment: Yes, I don't even know if it has a closed form. I couldn't find what type of sequences don't have a closed form.

Comment: Do you really need the closed form? Since for $x > 0$, $0 < x e^{-x} < x$. If you start from $a_0 > 0$, then $a_n$ will be a strictly decreasing sequence bounded  from below by $0$. It will converge to some $y \ge 0$. Since the map $x \mapsto xe^{-x}$ is continuous, the limit $y$ satisfies $y = ye^{-y} \implies  y = 0$. You don't need the closed form of $a_n$ to compute the limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer doesn't contain a closed form expression for sequence $a_n$. I don't believe it has one. In this answer, we try to study how fast $a_n$ decreases to $0$.

Let $f(x) = x e^{-x}$. Notice $0 < f(x) < x$ whenever $x > 0$, the sequence $(a_n)$ defined by the recurrence relation

$$a_n = \begin{cases} 1, & n = 0 \\ f(a_{n-1}), & n > 0\end{cases}$$
is a strictly decreasing sequence bounded from below by $0$. Since $f(x)$is continuous, limit
$a_\infty \stackrel{def}{=}\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists and $f(a_\infty) = a_\infty \implies a_\infty = 0$. This establish $a_n$ decreases to $0$.

To study how fast $a_n$ decreases to $0$, we look at sequence $\left(a_n^{-1}\right)$ instead. For $n \ge 0$, we have

$$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{a_n} e^{a_{n}} \ge \frac{1}{a_n}(1+a_n) = \frac{1}{a_n} + 1$$
This implies

$$\frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{1}{a_0} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( \frac{1}{a_{k+1}} - \frac{1}{a_k}\right) \ge 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1 = 1 + n$$
and hence $a_n$ decreases to $0$ at least as fast as $\frac{1}{n}$.

Let 
$$\Delta(x) = \frac{e^x - 1}{x} - 1 - \frac{x}{2} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}$$

Based on its power series expansion, we know $\Delta(x)$ is strictly increasing, positive and goes to zero as $O(x^2)$ for small $x$. Rewrite the recurrence relation once again, we get

$$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{a_n} e^{a_n} = \frac{1}{a_n} + 1 + \frac{a_n}{2} + \Delta(a_n)
$$
This leads to

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{a_n} &= n + 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{a_k}{2} + \Delta(a_k)\right)
\le n + 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\frac{1}{2k} + \Delta\left(\frac1k\right)\right]\\
&\le n + 1 + \frac12 H_n + C_0
\end{align}
$$
where $H_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ is the $n^{th}$ [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and $$C_0 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \Delta\left(\frac1k\right) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\zeta(n)}{(n+1)!} \approx 0.33493$$
It is known that
$H_n - \log(n+1)$ increases to [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) $\gamma \approx 0.5772156649$ as $n \to \infty$.
This leads to
$$\frac{1}{a_n} \le n + 1 + \frac12 \log(n+1) + C_1
\quad\text{ where }\quad C_1 = \frac{\gamma}{2} + C_0 \approx 0.62354
$$
Plug this upper bound back into the recurrence relation, we obtain

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_n} - 1 - \frac{1}{2(n+1)} 
&= \frac{1}{2a_n} - \frac{1}
{2(n+1)} + \Delta(a_n)\\
&\ge \frac12\left(\frac{1}{n + 1 + \frac12\log(n+1)+C_1} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
&\ge  -\frac14\frac{\log(n+1) + 2C_1}{(n+1)^2}
\end{align}
$$
Summing over different $n$, we can bound $\frac{1}{a_n}$ from both sides

$$-C_2 \le \frac{1}{a_n} - (n + 1 + \frac12 H_n) \le C_0
\quad\text{ where }\quad
C_2  = \frac14\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log(k) + 2C_1}{k^2} \approx 0.74723$$

If one look at error terms "within" $C_0$ and $C_2$ carefully, all of them have same
signs. The partial sums of these error term converge. As a result, following limit exists
$$C_\infty = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ \frac{1}{a_n} - \left( n + 1 + \frac12 H_n\right)\right]
\quad\in \quad(-C_2, C_0)
$$
The sequence $(a_n)$ decreases to $0$ essentially like 
$$a_n \approx\frac{1}{n + \frac12 \log n + C + o(1)}
\quad\text{ where }\quad C = 1 + \frac{\gamma}{2} + C_\infty \in (0.54137,1.62354)
$$
As a double check, following are numerical values of $\epsilon_n \stackrel{def}{=} \frac{1}{a_n} - (n + \frac12\log n )$ for selected $n$. It seems to be consistent with above analysis. For the last column, please refer to update below.

$$\begin{array}{r|ll}
n & \epsilon_n & 1/a_n - 1/a_n^{approx} \\
\hline
    5 & 1.452256585157472 & 0.000652156218441\\
   10 & 1.389752294761182 & 0.000282806941280\\
   20 & 1.349378753640906 & 0.000080828265304\\
   50 & 1.318816997359306 & 0.000011644667751\\
  100 & 1.306359480815289 & 0.000002370371917\\
  200 & 1.299203235322892 & 0.000000448836261\\
  500 & 1.294298879997029 & 0.000000045923002\\
 1000 & 1.292448816475257 & 0.000000007824838\\
 2000 & 1.291435425383042 & 0.000000001296712\\
 5000 & 1.290768538614429 & 0.000000000128239\\
10000 & 1.290525249116399 & 0.000000000009095\\
\end{array}
$$

**Update**

To proceed, we need to estimate the value of $C$. It is difficult to extract this value from $a_n$ directly as the convergence of $\epsilon_n$ to $C$ is very slow. As one can see from below, the leading correction of $\epsilon_n$ from $C$ is of the order $\frac{\log n}{n}$.

In order to estimate $C$, we employ the concept of [fractional function iterate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Fractional_iterates_and_flows,_and_negative_iterates).
We look for a function $\varphi : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\varphi(0) = 1$ and satisfies the functional equation

$$f(\varphi(x)) = \varphi(x+1)$$

It is easy to see $a_n = \varphi(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. As $x$ increases from $0$ to $\infty$, $\varphi(x)$ decreases from $1$ to $0$. If $\psi : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is the inverse function of $\varphi$, then $\psi(1) = 0$ and satisfy the [Abel equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation):

$$\psi(f(z)) = \psi(z) + 1$$

Since $\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{a_n} \sim n + \frac12\log n + C$ for large $n$, we expect
$\psi(z)$ has the form 
$$\psi(z) = \frac1z + \frac12 \log z - C + F(z)$$
for some function $F(z)$ which tends to $0$ as $z \to \infty$. Plug this into Abel equation and simplifies, we get

$$\frac1z e^z + \frac12(\log(z) - z) + F(ze^{-z}) = \frac1z + \frac12 \log z + F(z) + 1\\
\iff F(z) - F(ze^{-z}) = \frac1z\left( e^z - 1 - z - \frac{z^2}{2}\right)$$

Notice the cancellation of the problematic $\log z$ factor. There is nothing to stop $F(z)$ from having a power series expansion at $z = 0$. With help of a CAS,
we find

$$\begin{align} F(z) =  
\frac{z}{6}
&+\frac{z^2}{16}+\frac{19 z^3}{540}+\frac{z^4}{48}+\frac{41 z^5}{4200}+\frac{37z^6}{103680}-\frac{18349 z^7}{3175200}\\
&-\frac{443 z^8}{80640}+\frac{55721 z^9}{21555072}+\frac{84317 z^{10}}{6912000}
 +\frac{2594833561\,{z}^{11}}{399567168000}\\
&-\frac{152043613 z^{12}}{5748019200}-\frac{830066563 z^{13}}{17346700800}+\frac{209959420499 z^{14}}{3905587445760}\\& \;\;\vdots
\end{align}
$$
In principle, we can extract $C$ using the condition $\psi(1) = 0 \iff C = F(1)$.
However, this is not that accurate because the coefficients of $z^k$ in $F(z)$ doesn't decade quickly. A more accurate way is use the relation $\psi(a_n) = n$. This leads to

$$C = \frac{1}{a_n} + \frac12\log(a_n) + F(a_n) - n$$

With $n$ as small as $10$ and keeping $F(z)$ up to $z^{10}$, we already obtain a decent estimate $$C \approx 1.290247208687763$$

Once we have a reasonable estimate of $C$, we can invert the equation

$$n = \psi(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \frac12\log(z) - C + F(z)$$
and substitute the resulting $z$ by $a_n$. Using a CAS again, we find

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a_n} = n &+ \frac12\log n + C +
\frac{1}{12n}\left(6C-2 + 3\log n\right)\\
& - \frac{1}{48n^2}\left(
  (12C^2 - 20C + 7) + (12C-10)\log(n) + 3\log(n)^2\right)\\
& \;\;\vdots
\end{align}
$$
Let $a_n^{approx}$ be this approximation of $a_n$, the last column in the table above is the difference between $\frac{1}{a_n}$ and $\frac{1}{a_n^{approx}}$. As one can see, the differences decrease quickly. This partially validate the correctness of this approach and accuracy in estimation of $C$.

Comment: Ho my god, holy cow !!! Wow thank you very for this *extremely* detailed answer. I thought my question would just get ignored but this ! this is insane. Now I have to take a few days to understand what the hack you just wrote, but that's just a ton of cool math to learn ahead of me !

Comment: I'm assuming $\zeta(n)$ is the Reimann zeta function defined by $\zeta(n) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^n}$

Comment: @Canatime yes, $\zeta(n)$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: What is $o$ in the expression $a_n \approx\frac{1}{n + \frac12 \log n + C + o(1)}$

Comment: The $o(\cdots)$ is the [little o-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation), we say something is $o(h(n))$ if it converges to $0$ faster then $h(n)$ as $n \to \infty$, so $o(1)$ essentially means a correction which goes to zero as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Following my idea above, we look at $b_n=\ln(a_n)$, with $b_0=0$. The recursive relation becomes $$b_{n+1}=b_n-e^{b_n}$$

I claim that this sequence diverges to $-\infty$. It is clearly monotonically decreasing. Now, take any real number $X$. If $X\geq0$ then $b_1<X$ already. If $X<0$, note that for any $b_n>X$, we have $b_n\leq b_0-ne^X$. This implies that if $N$ is an integer such that $b_0-Ne^X<X$, then $b_N<X$ (as $b_N$ must be less than $X$ in order to possibly be larger than $b_0-Ne^X$).

This isn't any help in finding a closed form of $a_n$ or $b_n$, but at least it lets us find their limit.

Comment: But you don't need to transform the sequence for that conclusion. The $a_n$ are strictly decreasing and positive, therefore convergent. The only possible limit is zero (the solution of $x = xe^{-x}$).

Comment: @MartinR I know. But this way is more direct, relying on less theory. Anyone is welcome to choose their favourite approach, and this happens to be mine.